# Splitting one row into 2 rows based on data in one of the columns

Tags: r

I have a single row and I wish to split it onto 2 rows based on the value in one of the columns. So I want to split the value in the gender column using the + symbol and create 2 rows based on mens and womens here, (mens and womens will sometimes slightly change to man+woman so I want to stay consistent using the +. A better example of what I'm looking to do is below.

```
mydf
gender             country   date        field  latitude longitude
Mens1+Womens1      UK        20240226    both  NA        NA

mynewdf
gender       country   date        field  latitude longitude
Mens1        UK        20240226    both  NA        NA
Womens1      UK        20240226    both  NA        NA
```